# AngularJS: Cannot get my directive working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm in my second day of learning AngularJS and have a simple example of how to change DOM on user's action, which somehow does not work for me. Here is an examlple:

html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../Scripts/Controllers/app.js"></script>
   <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
   <my-widget>
      <p>Hello World</p>
   </my-widget>
</body>
</html>
```

File with directive's action:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive("my-widget", function () {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        var paragraph = element.children()[0];
        $(paragraph).on("click", function () {
            $(this).css({ "background-color": "red" });
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

Nothing happens when clicking on paragraph.
Cannot find why.

Comment: Directive names must be camel cased. `app.directive("myWidget", function () {` inorder to be able to use it as `my-widget` in the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your directive name to camelCasing, which angular will translate to `my-widget`. In addition, the jQuery `$` alias is not available and shouldn't be used with angular.  You already have the element, so interact with it directly, using `element.css()` to change css properties.

In addition, based on the comments below, it makes more sense to change the restrict to either "A" or "EA" and apply the directive directly to the element you intend to change.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../Scripts/Controllers/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div my-widget style="width: 300px; height: 200px; background-color: orange;">
    <p>Hello World</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This also saves you from needing to traverse to the child elements.

```
app.directive("myWidget", function () {
    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {
        element.on("click", function () {
          element.css("background-color", "red");
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

See this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDwpzhxxuxeg9EMCjMxH?p=preview).

Per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).
>
> The normalization process is as follows:
>
> Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes. Convert
>   the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

Comment: @David L Thank's, it works! However, I noticed, it only works with `<div my-widget`>. It does not work if I have `<my-widget>` only. Why is that?

Comment: When using "E", you are creating your own elements.  As a result, if you wanted to do something like that you really should also provide a template that tells the directive what to render.  As it stands right now, `<my-widget>` is simply a shapeless custom element that has no styling or body to it.  If you provided a template, it would inject the content and then you would be able to manipulate the template.  a restrict type of just "A" and adding your directive as just an attribute is probably your safest bet.